# Puppeteer trigger for navigation tabs

Tags: node.js, typescript, puppeteer

I have a page which looks like this:
[image]

I would like to do a screenshot with puppetee which should work as followed:

1. A web page, the script will type a date into a date-range input, and click a button, and then data will be displayed.
2. There are several tabs in this page (as can be seen in the red line box in the picture), every tab has a link link to a table which displays the  data. One tab per table.
3. The screenshot content is this whole page and one of tabs and table .
4. Click on another tab lead to table content smoothly change. the problem is that I do not know when this change is done? Is there any trigger provided by puppeteer?

source code:

```
private async doScreenShotGlobal(page: puppeteer.Page, dayStartStr: string) {
    const tabs = await page.$$('div.ant-tabs-tab');  // get tabs
    this.logger.info(tabs.length);
for (let j = 1; j <= tabs.length; j++) {  // process each tab

    let activeTab = await page.waitFor(`selector path > div:nth-child(${j})`);

    await activeTab.click(); 

    await page.waitForSelector('.ant-table-row.ant-table-row-level-0', { visible: true, timeout: 30000 }); // wait for table to appear

    await page.waitFor(1000); // i clicked another tab,but active tab does not change yet, so wait for 1000,but not work properly.

    const globalName = await page.$$eval('div.ant-tabs-tab-active.ant-tabs-tab', nodes => nodes.map(n => n.innerHTML));
    this.logger.info(j);
    this.logger.info(globalName);
    const fullName = `${this.saveMainpath}/${globalType}/${globalType}_${globalName}_${dayStartStr}.png`;
    const table = await page.$('div.ant-tabs-tabpane.ant-tabs-tabpane-active');
        if (table && !fs.existsSync(fullName)) {

          await this.shotOnFullPage(table, page, fullName); // to do screenshot

        }
        else {
          // ...
        }
      }

}
  }
```

and my dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "12.7.2",
    "log4js": "5.0.0",  
    "moment": "2.24.0",
    "puppeteer-core": "1.19.0",
    "merge-img": "2.1.3"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/puppeteer":"1.19.1",
    "@types/puppeteer-core":"1.9.0",
    "dayjs":"1.8.15",
    "@types/minimist":"1.2.0"
}
```

Comment: While clicking on a tab - do you expect any certain element to appear? or maybe even certain text?

Answer (score 0):

If the data in those tabs is static, you could use [page.waitForSelector](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.20.0/docs/api.md#pagewaitforselectorselector-options) to wait for the correct selector to appear.

Another way could be to use [page.evaluate](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.20.0/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) to manipulate the tables in the tabs to add an `id` attribute which can be used for *page.waitForSelector*.

If a HTTP request has to be done, you could listen to [*response*](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.20.0/docs/api.md#event-response) events and look for those HTTP requests.

Another (dirty) solution I can think of is to repeatedly check if the *innerHTML* of that table has changed.

Comment: those data in those tables  will be  fetched when form submit ,and all table's data will fetched. when i click a inactive tab, page will hidden current table, and display the table linked to the tab i clicked. so  table's content would not change. and page.waitForSelector()  what i meet is that  i wait for table's active structure(class ,attributes etc.) but, if there is a  table displayed , this wait-for-Method will return immediately.  
thank you for your help!

Comment: So every tab has the same structure and uses the same CSS classes? If not, you could use a different selector for every tab.

Comment: Since the data is static and available after form submission, you could also use `evaluate` to just manipulate the tab-tables in the DOM tree - I'll updated my answer accordingly

Comment: the only different is in-active / active (class name) , when i click a in-active tab, this in-active change to active, but table not changed immediately, it has a canvas animation, i do not know how to listen  animation event.  i am now working on changing dom element css directly by page.$$eval().